# Two separate "if"'s, same condition -- is it OK?

Tags: c++, syntax

Which of the two, do you think, is better?

```
if (the_condition)
{
    variable = sth;
}
else
{
    variable = sth_else;
}

if (the_condition)
{
    variable_2.doSth();
}
else
{
    variable_2.doSthElse();
}
```

or

```
if (the_condition)
{
    variable = sth;
    variable_2.doSth();
}
else
{
    variable = sth_else;
    variable_2.doSthElse();
}
```

I ask about it because the second example is obviously shorter. On the other hand in the first example operations on different variables are separated, thus probably easier to read.

Do you consider any of them better? Or is it pointless to ask such a question as it does not matter?

Comment: btw, the first option should probably be replaced with the ternary operator, since both branches just assign different values to the same variable.

Comment: If the compiler has optimizations enabled, it probably generates the same machine code for both. In terms of readability and in the context of the code, it depends what is more important to emphasize: the condition or separating what the effects are on the variable.

Comment: @Oak the ternary operator is a style preference, there's no reason why it "should" be used instead of an if block except if that's your personal preference.

Comment: the more i think about it (see comments on Jon's answer below), i think without further information it's not so much that it's "pointless" to ask such a question but that it's unanswerable without knowing more about the specifics of each identifier and even perhaps a little insight into the purpose of the code.  it's a very necessary question to ask yourself, but in the context of a real problem.

Comment: If `the_condition` depends on the value of `variable`, then you must use the first form; if not, the second is probably easier to read.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

### #2

What if the condition changes? Then you'd have to update it in *n* places! (And it's easy to miss one, introducing subtle, hard-to-find bugs.)

I personally find #1 much harder to read, since I have to read the condition for each assignment because it *might* be different. With #2, I know that everything in the `if` body is in the context of a single condition -- you might say that the condition encapsulates a single, cohesive multi-statement chunk of behaviour.

Of course, if the statements in the body of an `if` are unrelated (i.e. *not* part of the same chunk of behaviour), then they should be in separate `if`s. That's probably not the case here, though: You're setting up variables depending on an initial condition (which is likely one logical operation).

Comment: Also we better hope there that the_condition is not a function of variable otherwise the two could give different behaviour. A little factitious I know, but important to note.

Comment: @Dan: Good point, that could get very confusing quickly! Along the same lines, the body of one if (or else!) could potentially (perhaps even accidentally) affect the next if's condition. Eek!

Comment: @Cameron: on the other hand, if the two just accidentally happen to (at the moment) be decided by the same condition, but are distinct functionally, then tying them together may not be a good idea.

Comment: @Matthieu: Right. That's what I tried to convey in my last paragraph :-)

Comment: @Cameron: I missed it somehow.. doh!

Comment: I think the best answer is: "it depends". I agree with @Cameron, that generally it should fall under #2 condition, but there are cases that #1 applies (i.e. when "if"s are too large to read them). The rule of thumb here would be (as everywhere else) that code should be easy to read, and variables lifespan relatively short. Thanks!

Comment: @sthlm58: No problem :-) If the `if`s are too long to read, though, I'd consider grouping their contents into meaningful chunks of statements, and moving each chunk into its own function. (this would keep the `if` short and easy to read).

Answer (score 14):

Repeating conditions for no reason is not good, neither for performance (probably doesn't matter) nor for maintenance (**does matter**).

Your view that operations on variables should be separated is not shared by most programmers. The common view is that control flow should be kept as simple as possible, which is the case for the second option.

Comment: @Joey: "Even a C++ compiler" sounds strange. C++ is among the most mature programming language w.r.t. compiler optimizations.

Comment: You must be using too old or severely bad compilers then, or you are using the wrong flags. Possibly you also have a lot of undefined behaviour? The C compiler I use follows the C standard, same for the C++ compiler of choice. Which compiler/version do you have experience with? Alternatively, which language would you recommend? (a very interesting C++ example for auto-vectorization of a non-trivial loop: Search for [Flying Pig Squadrons](http://ompf.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=896), note this was with an old g++ version; more examples exist)

Comment: While C++ has certainly many points that prevent optimizations (most notably its aliasing rules), its compilers are still very sophisticated at optimizing what they can. I think we're talking about two different topics here.

Comment: @Alexander Gessler: "C++ has certainly many points that prevent optimizations" -> So do most programming languages. On the other side, though, C++ comes with many features that make it even more suitable to optimization than C (except for strict pointers). But I agree on the topic thing, especially because it is gcc/g++ which has phenomenal abilities to transform control flow (thanks to science and graphite in particular), which was what @Joey was complaining about.

Comment: Little afternote because otherwise @Joey has driven this micro-discussion all invalid by deleting his comments: @Joey said even a C++ compiler might optimize (read: transform) the control flow in the OP. Later he claimed C and C++ compilers would optimize code so much that it would become buggy.

Answer (score 10):

Many good reasons to prefer the second option have already been given, but there's another one: the structure of the first option doesn't match the way most people think. Does your own brain work like this?

```
If I go to the store I'll buy milk.
If I go to the store I'll buy eggs.
If I go to the store I'll get cash from the ATM.
```

Or like this?

```
If I go to the store I'll buy milk, buy eggs, and get cash from the ATM.
```

Comment: Haphazard versus organized thinking. Very nice.  (Aside: The allusion to the manner in which most people think may be incorrect. Haphazard is probably the more prevalent thinking mode.)

Comment: @DavidHammen That's a great point. People often do *think* in the haphazard way, and that's surely one of the biggest problems in software development. I should have used *communicate* or *learn*. Writing good code is at least as much about clearly presenting intent as it is about getting correct results.

Answer (score 8):

The compact version; I find this most readable, and generally it would be how I approach it my code... YMMV, of course. ;)

```
// the safest way; it protects you from unexpected results in cases
// where the evaluation of "the_condition" has side-effects, or where
// it may be changed in the future to have them (as can often happen, 
// for instance, when a class field is changed to a property)
var theCondition = the_condition;

variable1 = theCondition ? sth           : sth_else;
variable2 = theCondition ? sth_different : sth_even_more_different;

// if evaluating "the_condition" has no side-effects, and you can be
// fairly sure it never will, then you can do this, but be careful:
variable1 = the_condition ? sth           : sth_else;
variable2 = the_condition ? sth_different : sth_even_more_different;
```

Not specific to any particular answer, remember (in cases where the results may be used multiple times) it's good practice to assign the results to appropriately-scoped variables (local if they are transient, or perhaps object or class (static) properties when they are more permanent) that are named in a way that reveals the conceptual nature of the results (e.g., not variable1 and variable2 :D).

By evaluating things only as often as needed, you will make your code more clear conceptually (assuming you do give good names to the variables you assign the evaluation to), and the compiled code will usually be more efficient (and will almost never be less efficient).

[Thanks to Peter Wone for suggesting in the comments that the point about multiple evaluations should be more explicit.]

---

It is also possible to use the following:

```
        switch (the_condition)
        {
            case true:
                variable1 = sth;
                variable2 = sth_else;
                break;

            case false:
                variable1 = sth_different;
                variable2 = sth_even_more_different;
                break;

        }
```

although I think it would be rare for that to be the appropriate solution; I mention it for completeness since I had not seen it suggested yet.

As I mentioned in my response to a comment, below, a possible example for the `case` statement would be if all of the following hold:

- this check is within a finite state machine
- `the_condition` represents a state of the FSM
- <s>`the_condition`'s type FSM will likely be changed to an 
  enumerated type at some point</s>
    Upon reflection:

  - It seems to me that a Boolean conceptually representing something other than a truly binary [yes/no|off/on|true/false]-type option *should be*, regardless, treated as something other than a binary value since:

    - I think that, wherever feasible, code should be representing concepts rather than implementation details.
    - Choosing a Boolean value to represent a non-binary option would be an accidental feature of your implementation, rather than the conceptual nature of the option.
    - This could easily happen even in circumstances where you will likely *never* change the variable to an enumerated type.
    - And, this meets the feasibility condition, as representing this choice with a `case` is feasible here. [There is an assumption made here: either this is not in a tight loop, or the compiler optimizes the code to be no more intensive than a conditional, or that the code performs acceptably regardless.]

  Example/Reasoning:

  - You are writing a custom FSM that under certain conditions must choose items from one of two internal lists to feed to some well-worn implementation of an algorithm:

    - The implementation you are using only works when items are chosen, one from each list, either from front to back or from back to front.
    - A Boolean called `UseFifoAlgorithm` is chosen to be the property determining whether to pull items in a FIFO or LIFO manner.
    - So, in this case, `UseFifoAlgorithm` represents a choice of front-to-back but its negation "`!UseFifoAlgorithm`" does not conceptually equate to "Don't use a front-to-back algorithm to pull from the lists." but, rather, to "Use a back-to-front algorithm to pull from the lists."
    - Since negating the value would not mean the same thing as negating the concept behind it, using a negation of the value as a determinant in the code does not represent, conceptually, what is really going on, and it, therefore, seems inappropriate to use it so.
    - As the `case` statement is the construct which best represents (conceptually) making a choice between non-binary possibilities, and since it's been shown that this is not (conceptually) a binary choice, the `case` statement is a far more appropriate choice to represent the nature of the comparison.
    - Therefore, assuming that the code performs adequately to the task, the `case` statement is feasible, and, therefore, should be used (probably with comments above the 'true' and 'false' designating which method is chosen) rather than a conditional.

Okay, I know, a lot of text for a rare case, but this is the example that comes to my mind because I have often used Boolean values to maintain or define states or options in an attempt to avoid creating an enumerated value. In some of those cases I was just trying to ["Do the Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work"](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoTheSimplestThingThatCouldPossiblyWork), but in some cases I was making a poor design decision because I was too reluctant to created that enumerated value.

So, having shown that there are some possible cases where a Boolean really might be appropriate for such a choice, I think the biggest value of this example is that, I will be more likely to consider this as an option in such cases, and therefore will also be more likely to consider whether or not, indeed, a Boolean is appropriate: when there really is a forced choice between one of two possibilities, but the negation of one does not conceptually imply the second. Seems like in other cases it's probably better to bite the bullet and create the `enum`.

If for some reason it's undesirable to expose an additional `enum` to users of the class, or to users of a library, or what-have-you, then it's still probably worth considering using an `enum` internally to represent the choice, and then using an int or multiple booleans or something similar to expose the choice to the outside world.

Comment: +1 for the ternary option - especially if you align the colons.  That way, it's easy to scan down the results for each value of the_condition.  For readability, this makes both dimensions equally readable.

Comment: good point; edited... (ftfm?) :D

Comment: The second version is good, the first doesn't really make sense.  switch for a simple if-else is overkill, neither simpler nor easier to read.

Comment: well, to my eyes, in this case, not more complicated or harder to read. and, i can imagine a context in which it would be more expressive. say: this class is an FSM, "the_condition" represents a state, and you knew when you wrote the code that it was likely going to be changed to an enum soon... i didn't say it was the right choice in all circumstances, i just offered it as something i hadn't seen yet.

Comment: I think this is a nice tidy answer but there *is* one thing it doesn't make explicit, although the way the last sample is written does tend to suggest it: evaluate the condition once and keep the result, then use it as many times as makes your code simple.

Answer (score 3):

I 'd say **it depends on your business model**.

If the two variables are guaranteed to always have their values set "as one", then the second approach should be used to reflect that (and possibly a comment added to reinforce this).

Otherwise, if the two conditions *happen* to be the same (but there is no requirement saying that they cannot diverge in the future), the first approach should be used.

No matter which of the above holds, replacing the conditional assignments with the ternary operator where convenient would also produce shorter code.

Comment: There are many places that ban the use of the ternary operator. The excuse is that it is too confusing. I don't agree with that sentiment at all, but it is something to be aware of.

Comment: This is what I was going to say, and I'm disappointed that many (admittedly well-written) comments saying "most probably, the two variables are supposed to be in sync, therefore I will answer on that basis" are voted above it. I'd also comment on the ternary operator: if initialising the variable is ALL that block of code is doing then the ternary operator may be more useful, but I would bet money that it's easy to think of as two separate blocks of initialisation rather than one variable initialisation.

Comment: truly the devil is in the details here; the way the code in the original question is written shows "the_condition" as a simple boolean variable and then two initializations of simple variables by other simple variables or constants.  in that case, i like the ternary way better.  were "the_condition" to be considered a placeholder for what-e'er-you-will, e.g. function etc., then i would steer towards a switch or the single eval if/else.  and i think Jon's answer is spot on: "it depends".  without knowing the actual domain i can give my general feeling, but the reality might be quite different.

Comment: oh, sorry for the double comment; but also: i didn't even think (until now) about the fact that it could all be properties, each with side-effects that i didn't know about, in which case my answers could really be off-base. :)

Answer (score 3):

My personal preference:

```
T const variable = foo(v1, v2);
T2 const variable2 = bar(v1, v2);
```

A variable declared `const` cannot be changed (ah!) and therefore debugging is made so much easier because you can assume it won't change (otherwise the compiler would have complained).

In general, I would recommend writing short methods, but short does not mean "compact", it means performing few tasks.

Answer (score 2):

**#2 is cleaner**, but I often end up doing the following if there is a clear *main path* in the code and the extra variable assignment doesn't generate much more work.

```
variable = sth_else;
variable_2 = sth_even_more_different;

if (the_condition)
{
    variable = sth;
    variable_2 = sth_different;
}
```

Other shorthand, which some argue is a bad practice. Don't use too much:

```
variable = the_condition ? sth : sth_else;
variable_2 = the_condition ? sth_different : sth_event_more_different;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would consider the **second** better. Grouping the logic for a particular condition in one block allows easier maintenance in the future. At one glance of the code a reader can associate a given conditional control flow with its corresponding program logic without having to keep reading further down the page. The grouping also allows changes to happen in isolation without having to worry about updating other blocks.

Answer (score 1):

May I advocate another approach?

You seem to be assigning to the same set of variables in each if-body. Sets of variable sounds like at least a `POD aggregate` to me:

```
struct Foo {
    int variable;
    int variable_2;
};
```

---

## Variant I

Then

```
const Foo alpha = {sth, sth_different},
          bravo = {sth_else, sth_even_more_different};
...
Foo foo;
if (the_condition)
    foo = alpha;
else
    foo = bravo;

// or something like  const Foo foo=get(the_condition);
```

---

## Variant II

Or the more const-correct version with less mutable state and actual initialisation:

```
const Foo alpha = {sth, sth_different},
          bravo = {sth_else, sth_even_more_different};
...
const Foo foo = the_condition ? alpha
                              : bravo;
```

---

## Variant III

Or in benchmarked, time critical, bottleneck code (but totally depends, as said, **benchmarked**), a good old lookup table:

```
const Foo foos[] = {{sth, sth_different},
                    {sth_else, sth_even_more_different}};
...
const Foo foo = foos[the_condition?0:1];
```

---

## Variant IV

Depending on your actual use case, it might even be more natural to inverse the thing:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo (bool condition) : [...] {...}
};
```

---

## Appendix

### Enforcement of initialization

The nice thing about introducing a class/struct is that it also enables the enforcement of not forgetting an initialization:

```
class Foo {
    Foo (int var_a, int var_b) : var_a(var_a), var_b(var_b) {}

    const int var_a;
    const int var_b;

private:
    Foo(); // or "= delete" in upcoming standard
};
```

### Performance

Interestingly, even an old gcc of the 3.x line will compile both variants ...

```
#include <iostream>
int pure() {                  
    bool cond;
    std::cin >> cond;        
    int a, b;    
    a = cond ? 0 : 2;
    b = cond ? 1 : 3;        
    std::cout << a << "," << b << std::endl;
}

struct Foo {
    int a, b;
};
int agg() {
    const Foo alpha = { 0, 1 },
              bravo = { 2, 3 };                  
    bool cond;
    std::cin >> cond;        
    const Foo result = cond ? alpha : bravo;        
    std::cout << result.a << "," << result.b << std::endl;
}
```

... into something that differs by only 2-6 assembly instructions, compared to 80-120 instructions in total. I lack a modern g++ right now, unfortunately. But already with this really dated compiler, using aggregates doesn't smell to me (if I find the time, I'll present the results later).

Comment: Allocating two for no reason (one is always discarded) seems like an exceptionally strange choice.

Comment: It provides more coherency and consistency in the code, and further it enables to enforce to not forget an initialization. Furthermore, if you smell bad performance there, your compiler is exceptionally outdated. But well, if down-voting because of code-quality gives you a good night, I am happy.

Answer (score 1):

The second choice is generally better. It is the control flow of the function as a whole that is typically of greater importance. Many projects have rules to keep the decision logic down to a minimum. That decision logic is a measurable quantity, McCabe's cyclomatic complexity or some variant of it such as extended cyclomatic complexity.

**Comment on style**
It's a good idea to get out of the habit of writing

```
if (the_condition)
  variable = sth;
else
  variable = sth_else;
```

Always use braces. Adding braces doesn't change the compiled code one iota. The cost to the author in adding those braces is minimal; with a smart editor the cost can be non-existant. The potential savings in reduction of stupid, hard to chase down bugs is immense. There are many, many projects that make code of the form above illegal because of this. Always use braces.

Comment: you are very adamant about the braces there; what sort of bugs do you see occurring?  if someone tries to add in an extra statement, vb-style, between the if and the else, it will get flagged as an error. and the cost to the author is that now something which was already not that compact becomes even less compact.

at the least the mono project does not agree with your assesment.  http://www.mono-project.com/Coding_Guidelines

Comment: @shelley: You are right. I am very adamant on that one. Regarding Mono project: Seriously? Vertical space is a precious resource?? There are many, many projects that mandate braces after if, else, do, for. A tiny sample: CERN, many at DoD and NASA (e.g. Joint Strike Fighter), National Radio Astronomy Observatory, Applied Informatics, ...

Comment: i realize there are many projects that mandate it; i do not argue against it being a good idea to have style guides so that there is a standard way of doing things. and yes, seriously, vertical space is important to me; and i think there's room for disagreement as to whether there's "one true way" in this case.  and naming off places that have chosen the other style does not answer the question i posed: what exactly are these "stupid, hard to chase down bugs" that generate an "immense" savings in the long run?  i am genuinely curious since i have never once been bitten by this.

Comment: This rule that I'm adamant on takes on even more importance nowadays than it did in the past. Imagine that your project manager just hired someone to maintain your code; the newbie has a lot of python experience, very little C++ experience.

Comment: He should not maintain C++ unless appropriately trained. Why should he?

Comment: I advocate exactly the opposite. When I see a single statement enclosed in braces, I assume there were intended to be more statements there, and somehow the others accidentally got deleted or something. When I see this misbegotten mess, I immediately assume the code is buggy -- and I'm afraid that turns out to be correct *far* more often than not. IMO, including braces "just because" is a really lousy idea, and causes more problems than it cures.

Comment: See also http://producingoss.com/en/common-pitfalls.html#bikeshed .

Comment: The point of the always-use-braces rule isn't to catch an extra line inserted in the `if` clause of an if/else statement -- the compiler will of course complain if you do that. The rule is to catch a line added to an `if` clause that's not followed by an `else`, or one added to an `else` clause, or to the body of a `for`, `while`, or `do` loop. Perhaps more importantly, people *reading* the code don't have to look at every second statement after an unbraced single statement and wonder if it could be a bug.

Comment: @Caleb: If you fear so much for bugs in such places, may I recommend the [Anti If-Campaign](http://www.antiifcampaign.com/index.html) to you (just for the basic ideas)? Or, if code at your place is so complex and state-full that mere mortals have problems reading it, may I recommend introducing named functions and more const correctness instead?

Comment: @phresnel, I don't fear bugs, but I do like to avoid those that can be easily avoided. Always using braces is one tiny bit of coding style that helps quite a bit.

Comment: @Caleb - i just haven't had that experience... in an environment where everyone is using Visual Studio, coding in C#, and things are automatically tabified, i don't actually have to check that and wonder. if i see two unbraced statements after an else, i don't have to think it might be a bug, because only the first one can be in the else! @phresnel, i don't really care all that much, if my style guide said to use braces, i would use braces. i just challenged the extremely strong statement that was made regarding the "immense" impact it has.  i certainly haven't experienced that.

Comment: @shelleybutterfly: I don't care much either. But I highly doubt the relevantness and significance of braces, when C++ is so much more complicated and at times inhuman. @Caleb: Polymorphism in general and C++'s collection of algorithms help you to avoid explicit control flow. Especially the upcoming standard will lead this so much further.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add one more variant I think it as least worth considering. If you only use it in one place for a single binary condition, it's probably overkill. If you're likely to encounter greater complexity or use it a lot, it can be considerably more useful.

```
// type for pointer to member function
typedef void (*variable_2_type::pmf)();

// type holding value and action to execute:
struct result { 
    T value;
    pmf action;
};

// table of values/actions:
result results[] = { 
    {sth_else, &variable_2_type::doSthElse },
    {sth,      &variable_2_type::doSth }
};

// use the table:
variable = results[condition]. value;
variable_2.*(results[condition].action)();
```